# How To Generate A Value Based On Assigned Probability In R?

Tags: r, random, probability

I am trying to assign individuals to a site. What I want is to make the probability of choice proportional to two location attributes, in this case, square footage and population density. So, choice is a function of sq. footage and population density.

I want to assign a specific population density to a particular location when it is randomly drawn. So, let's say site A was selected out of the random draw and in this scenario I am making site A the best site. In that, it would be assigned to 0 population density. Site A is assigned to the lowest population density 0 because it is the best site. Only at low population density, an individual is assigned to site A. B would = 0.5 population density (second to best site), C would =1.0 (third to best site), and so on.

Below is what I have so far:

```
nindiv=100 #create individuals
prob=c(.0,.1,.2,.3,.4) # here I think I need to add an additional probability, not sure

prob=prob/sum(prob)  #normalize prob so it adds to 1
cumprob=c(0,cumsum(prob)) #make a vector that is the boundaries of the probability for each individual

head(cumprob)

#I chose a random number between 0 and 1 for each individual and see where within cumprob this random number falls
#so now cumprob is 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.3 0.6 1.0

#if the random number for an individual is less than 0.1 it goes to site 2

#if the random number is less than 0.3 but greater than 0.1 it goes to site 3

#if the random number is less than 0.6 but greater than 0.3 it goes to site 4

#if the random number is less than 1 but greater than 0.6 it goes to site 5

rdraw=runif(nfish,min=0,max=1)  #here is the random number for each individual
choice=array(dim=nfish)  #this will store the section chosen for each individual

for (indiv in 1:nindiv) {
low=which(cumprob<rdraw[indiv] ) #this is a vector of which cumprobs are less than the random number
choice[indiv]=low[length(low)]   #if the random number was 0.05 then low would be  1, 2
                                 #and the site assigned would be 2

 } #end of individual loop
```

Is there some way to incorporate an interaction between square footage and density that influences an individual's decision to select a site? Is an interaction what I need?

Comment: I am confused. What do those probabilities mean? How are they related to sq. footage and population density?

Comment: Hi, ekoam. For example, I would expect that there is a 75% chance/probability that an individual would select the best site (largest sq. footage say 56 sq.ft) if the population density in that site was low, say 0.1. However, I would expect a lower percentage/probability say 25% that an individual would select the best site if the population density was high say 0.5. Does that make more sense? I'm sorry if this confusing.

Comment: I may need a conditional probability.

Comment: OK, then how to determine the population density of a site? Is it just a random variable following a uniform distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is just random. I would include 4 possible population densities an individual could be randomly assigned such as 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5. Let's say the best site is A and the worst site is D. If an individual gets randomly assigned a population density 0 it would select A, if an individual was assigned a population density 0.5, it would select site B, and so on.

Comment: Is this what you want? First, randomly shuffle a set of four sites A, B, C and D with the probabilities of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and 0.4, respectively. Assume that BADC is the result. Then, randomly select a population density out of four numbers 0, 0.5, 1 and 1.5. Return B if 0 is selected, A if 0.5 is selected and so on?

Comment: @ekoam Yes, exactly, except for one thing: I want to assign a specific population density to a particular site when it is randomly drawn. So, let's say site A was selected out of the random draw and in this scenaio I am making site A the best site. In that, it would be assigned to 0 population density. Site A is assigned to the lowest population density 0 because it is the best site. Only at low population density, an individual is assigned to site A. B would = 0.5 population density (second to best site), C would =1.0 (third to best site), and so on.

Comment: So something like this? First, randomly shuffle a set of four sites A, B, C and D with the probabilities of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and 0.4, respectively. Assume that BADC is the result. Then, randomly select a population density out of four numbers 0, 0.5, 1 and 1.5. Assume that 1 is selected. Return C? @crew4u

Comment: Yes, that's it! @ekoam